# Função de Excluir e Consultar- Python

Tags: python, array, lista

Tenho que fazer um programa simples em Python. No caso uma biblioteca , porém estou tendo dificuldades na função de consultar e excluir. Eu sinceramente travei, tentei de varias formas mas não consegui.

Meu código está assim, qual o meu erro ?

```
livro=[]
opc = 0
i = 0

def incluirLivro():
    idLivro=[]
    print("Digite o id do Livro")
    idLivro.append(int(input()))
    livro.append(idLivro)
    titulo=[]
    print("Digite o titulo do Livro")
    titulo.append(input())
    livro.append(titulo)
    autor = []
    print("Digite o autor do Livro")
    autor.append(input())
    livro.append(autor)
    editora = []
    print("Digite o editora do Livro")
    editora.append(input())
    livro.append(editora)
    volume = []
    print("Digite o volume do Livro")
    volume.append(int(input()))
    livro.append(volume)
    ano = []
    print("Digite o ano do Livro")
    ano.append(int(input()))
    livro.append(ano)
    preco =[]
    print("Digite o preco do Livro")
    preco.append(float(input()))
    livro.append(preco)

def consultarLivro():
    id = int(input())
    for i in livro:
        if id == livro[i]:
            print(livro[i])
def excluirLivro():
    print('Informe o ID do livro que você deseja excluir')
    idLivro1 = int(input())
    if idLivro1 == livro[i]:
        del(livro[i])


while(opc != 5):
    print("\nMenu do livro\n\n")
    print("\n1 - Incluir\n")
    print("\n2 - Consultar\n")
    print("\n3 - Alterar\n")
    print("\n4 - Excluir\n")
    print("\n5 - Fim\n")
    print("\nDigite uma opção")
    opc = int(input())
    if(opc==1):
        incluirLivro()
    if(opc==2):
        consultarLivro()
    if(opc==3):
        alterarLivro()
    if(opc==4):
        excluirLivro()
    if(opc==5):
        print("Fim do programa......")
```

Answer (score 1):

a função `consultarLivro` se resolve da seguinte maneira:

adicionando `range(len(livro))`.

Isso resolve por que o index de listas só funcionam com **números** e não com **strings** que era o que você estava fazendo.

**Exemplo:**

`livro[0]`, que retornaria o primeiro elemento da lista, e aí comparava.

O que você estava fazendo : `livro['Titulo']`, que seria funcional caso fosse um **dicionário**.

Outra alteração que fiz foi por um `[0]` a frente do `livro[i]`, o motivo foi por que você fez com que todo conteúdo de `livro` fossem listas, veja:

```
[[299], ['t'], ['a'], ['e'], [12], [2017], [1.99]] # Retirado do console
```

Aí ele roda sem dar erro, porem você apenas pediu para imprimir novamente o livro[i], basicamente pedindo para imprimir o ID novamente(?).

ficando:

```
def consultarLivro():
    id = int(input('Digite o ID:'))
    for i in range(len(livro)):
        if id == livro[i]:
            print(livro[i])
```

e a saída:

```
>>> [299]
```

A função `excluirLivro()` foi basicamente a mesma coisa. Eu adicionei o `for` e aí ele deletou, mas deletou apenas o ID, o que é errado, mas agora ele deleta algo.

```
def excluirLivro():
    print('Informe o ID do livro que você deseja excluir')
    idLivro1 = int(input())
    for i in range(len(livro)):
        if idLivro1 == livro[i][0]:
            del(livro[i])
            break # Quando deletar, ele para o For, senão vai causar um erro.
```

`livro` **antes** : `[[299], ['t'], ['a'], ['e'], [12], [2017], [1.99]]`

`livro` **depois**: `[['t'], ['a'], ['e'], [12], [2017], [1.99]] # Deletando apenas o ID`

Bem, o que eu fiz acima foi só retirar os erros do seu código, mas ele ainda continua errado de certa forma, pois ele não imprime totalmente o livro, bem, aí é com você.

Se quiser uma dica, crie um dicionário, e em cada valor do dicionário terá um ID de cada livro, e dentro de cada ID terá os seus valores ( Titulo, etc... ), exemplo:

```
livros = {"299":["Titulo","Autor","Editora",2,2017,1.99],
"212":["Titulo2","Autor2","Editora2",2,2017,1.99]
}
```

Espero ter ajudado a deixar seu código mais claro.

Comment: Não ta dando certo , não aparece nada '-' e no excluir eu tô com dificuldade de apagar tudo mesmo

Comment: O certo na verdade é refazer todo seu código e se basear em dicionários, por listas fica impossível, eu acho.

Answer (score 0):

Procure prestar atenção no escopo das variáveis do seu programa.

Eu vi diversas listas que são criadas alteradas mas morrem após a chamada da função pois nenhuma função sua tem valor de retorno.

Vou dar um exemplo simples para vc entender escopo e dai vc pode tentar procurar o erro ou os erros no seu código e me dizer.

```
x = 5
def foo():
    x = 10
foo()
print(x) # valor printado é 5 pois a variável x de dentro da função só existe la dentro, não é possível acessá-la no programa principal.
```

Outro exemplo:

```
def foo1()
    var1 = 15
foo1()
print(var1) # Erro de sintaxe, variável var1 não existe.
```

Caso queira que a variável exista fora de uma função é necessário que ela RETORNE um ou mais valores Ex.:

```
def foo2()
    var2 = 13
    return var2
var2 = foo2() # faz a variável var2 receber o valor de retorno da função e existir fora do escopo de foo2. (O nome dessa variável não importa, poderia ser var0 = foo2() que daria na mesma)
```

Para concluir. Você pode retornar múltiplos valores em uma mesma função separando cada variável (expressão pra ser mais exato) por vírgula.

Exemplo:

```
def insereLivro():
    lista_livro = ['l1', 'l2', 'l3']
    lista_precos = [10, 20, 500]
    lista_editora = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3']
    return lista_livro, lista_precos, lista_editora
lista_livro, lista_precos, lista_editora = insereLivro()  # Novamente, os nomes das variáveis nesse linha podem ser diferentes dos nomes da função retorno, x1, x2, x3 = insereLivro() iria dar na mesma.
```

EDIT: Mais uma coisa, quando se está trabalhando com listas, que são estruturas de dados mutáveis, caso alguma lista seja passada por parametro para alguma função, a passagem é feita por referência, ou seja, se passar uma lista por parametro para uma função e dentro dessa função fizer alterações nessa lista, essas alterações serão refletidas no escopo global, mesmo que a lista nao seja retornada usando o comando `return`.

```
def appendlista(lista)
    lista.append(10)
lista = [1,2,3]
print(appendlista(lista)) # Resulta em [1,2,3,10]
```